# Mongoose: How to remove all documents with some field value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to remove all documents with the same value on a field ? I only know how to remove first occurrence which is shown below.

```
  topicRoutes.route("/delete/:id").post(function(req, res) {
    Topic.findOne({ user_id: req.params.id }).then(topic => {
      topic.delete();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`deleteMany`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany) to delete all documents that match the filters:

```
  topicRoutes.route("/delete/:id").post(function(req, res) {
    Topic.deleteMany({ user_id: req.params.id }, function (err) {});
  });
```